# extras.getString dynamic button?

Tags: java, android

I have the following:

```
</LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button1"/>
          <Button 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button2"
            android:onClick="clickButton"/>
```

activity1:

```
            public void clickButton(View v) {
                Button btn = (Button)v;
                String buttonText = btn.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PickChar2.class);
                intent.putExtra("button2", buttonText);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
```

activty 2:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String foo = extras.getString("button1"); // how do i accept any button?

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);
```

is there a way for getString to accept any button first, and then I do an if statement to see which buttons the user clicked and act accordingly? I want the user to be able to press button1, or button2, or 3, 4, etc...

the problem i have is that, there are 30 buttons in the first layout, and i don't want to make 30 intents and 30 extra.getStrings. what I'm hoping to do is something like:
-user 1 press1 button
- activity 1 passes that button to activity 2
- activity 2 checks which button was pressed
- do something

The buttons are in the different activity. I used an intent to pass the buttons from activity1 into this activity.

Comment: You are going to have to explain more of what you mean if you want a good answer. Where are these buttons? Same Activity? Give us some context?

Comment: Actually you can go reverse as well. For seeng which button the user cicked, define separate onClickLister for each of them. Then based on which ever is clicked just start a new activity r do whatever you want to do. If you want to pass different things via intent on different clicks, then pass that inside the listner.

Comment: See my answer. It should do what you need. Use one listener and you can use just one `Intent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the same listener for each `Button`, which I recommend in this situation, you can assign the text according to the `Button` clicked

```
public void onClick(View v) {
      Button btn = (Button)v;  // v is the Button that was clicked so cast it to a Button
      String buttonText = btn.getText().toString();  // and get its text here
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity2.class);  
      intent.putExtra("button1", buttonText);   // then send it on its way
      startActivity(intent);
```

Now in your next `Activity` you will get the text of the `Button` you clicked

**You want this**

To use one listener you can set the `android:onClick="functionName"` for each `Button` then use that function in your first `Activity`. So it would be like

```
public void functionName(View v)
{
      Button btn = (Button)v;  // v is the Button that was clicked so cast it to a Button
      String buttonText = btn.getText().toString();  // and get its text here
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity2.class);  
      intent.putExtra("button1", buttonText);   // then send it on its way
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

or you can do it in java by initializing each `Button`

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someId);
...
```

then setting the `onClickListener` for each

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and use the `onClick()` function like my very first example. But then you also have to remember to implement `OnClickListener`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
```

In this situation I recommend doing it in xml because it is basically copy/paste and you have one function and don't have to set listeners

Comment: hmm, a few questions while im trying to digest this.
Button btn = (Button)v  , why do i need this? I didn't have this in my code and it works. what's the purpose of this?
and by using:
intent.putExtra("button1", buttonText);

doesn't that assign the intent to react to 1 specific button? what if the user pressed button 2?

Comment: Basically use the second code snippet in my answer and the part about declaring the function in xml and you will be fine

Comment: I assume that `button` is a `Button` that you initialized in your code. Your code will give you the text of THAT `Button` but is it giving you the text of whichever`Button` was clicked?

Comment: in `public void onClick(View v)` `v` is the `Button` that was clicked as an Object so you have to cast it to a `Button` to get the text. This allows you to use the same function for all `Buttons` hence one listener. As long as you set the listeners in one of the two ways I showed at the end of my answer

Comment: it is giving me the text of that button. but ONLY that button. other buttons doesn't work because i only built an intent for "button1". it'd need to do this for all other buttons right? bascially have 30+ intents..

Comment: NO! That's what the second part of my answer was about. Set the function in xml for each `Button` then you just have to create that function and put the code in there. The `Button` clicked will be the v in `public void functionName(View v)`

Comment: Follow what I wrote right after **You want this** and that will give you one function, one `Intent` for all `Button`s

Comment: i just realized i left out the chunk of my code that defines the button. so instead of findViewById(R.id.button1), which only understands 1 button click, Button btn = (Button)v lets the activity understand any buttons?

Comment: Kind of...it casts whichever `View` was clicked to a `Button` since other `View`s can have `onClick`s. So you just have to define that function in your xml for each `Button`

Comment: Does that make sense to you now? Is it working as you need?

Comment: I'm getting The type MyActivity must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View). what does the "myactivity" do?

Comment: Where do you get `myActivity`??? If you set the onClick in xml then you don't need to implement OnClickListener. And you don't need to set one on your buttons

Comment: i edited my initial post.

if i remove "public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{"
 i get an error on my fucntion: 
void is an invalid type for the variable clickButton

Comment: Is `clickButton()` inside of a function like `onCreate()`? If so, it shouldn't be. Also, you need `public class MyActivity extends Activity` without `implements OnClickListener`

Comment: You are welcome! Glad we got it!